# Django Debug Toolbar doesn't show

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm using Django But Django Debug Toolbar doesn't **show** on Chrome & Firefox. I have done all steps for config, that said on the official site of Django-debug-toolbar.

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.9.0

Comment: urlpatterns = [path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)), ]

Comment: I added this line before

Comment: uplode your all setup code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved, I tested 127.0.0.1:8000 on Microsoft edge and everything was ok but on chrome, firefox and ie the toolbar did not show.

**If you have configured correctly and can't see the toolbar please check with other browsers, like edge**

Thanks all.